# I am getting NZEC error while submitting this code on codechef

Tags: python

[This is the problem, for which the code is below written in Python 2.7.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pngf9.jpg)
     [This is the example Input and output for the same problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZXMY.jpg)

This is the code, which is working fine on my machine. But while submitting it in Codechef there is a problem named NZEC error, from which I am not familiar with and don't know how to debug that.

```
##Reverse Function

def reverse(member):
    if len(member) <= 1:
        return member
    return reverse(member[1:]) + member[0]

##Sum of Position

def positionsum(member):
    checker = len(member)/2
    realsum = 0
    while checker != -1:
        realsum = checker + realsum + 1
        checker = checker - 1
    return realsum

##Sum of those values at that Position

def valuesum(member):
    checker = len(member)/2
    sumis = 0
    while checker != -1:
        sumis = int(member[checker]) + sumis
        checker = checker - 1
    return sumis


stop = 0

##Entering Cases

inp = int(raw_input(''))
lst = list()

##INPUT OF ALL THE MEMBERS & STRIPS

while (inp > stop):
    member = ''

    ##Entering Strips

    strips = int(raw_input(''))

    ##Entering Members

    member = raw_input('')

    if len(member) > strips:
        print 'Wrong Input'
        continue

    lst.append(member)
    stop = stop + 1
print lst

##CHECKING FOR ELIGIBILITY

for member in lst:
    new_string = ''
    real_sum = 0
    sum_is = 0

    if len(member)%2 != 0 and member[0] == '1':
        new_string = reverse(member)
        real_sum = positionsum(member)
        sum_is = valuesum(member)
        if member == new_string and real_sum == sum_is:
            print 'yes'
        else:
            print 'no'
    if member[0] != '1' or len(member)%2 == 0:
        print 'no'
```

Comment: Many coding challenge judge programs will emit a NonZero Exit Code when the program is taking too long to execute. Try to reduce the big O complexity of your code; that usually helps.

Comment: Can you reduce the complexity of this code?

Comment: If you're asking "is it possible to reduce the complexity of the code?", at a glance I think you can get it down to a reasonable O(N). If you're asking, "can you, Kevin, reduce the complexity of the code for me?", I think that would be a violation of the spirit of the competition :-)

Comment: Okay, Can you at least tell me, how to start for reduction of the complexity and how to test new code? What kind of complexity we are talking about, is it time taken to run this program or memory used. Because it is not mentioned.